# Stripe API Balance

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve my Stripe balance using the Stripe API with PHP.

I am calling the following:

```
function retrieve_balance()
{
   $response = Stripe_Balance::retrieve();

   return $response;
}
```

This returns something like this:

```
object(Stripe_Balance)#28 (5) {
  ["_apiKey":protected]=>
   string(32) "my_key_here"
   ["_values":protected]=>
    array(4) {
     ["pending"]=>
       array(1) {
         [0]=>
           object(Stripe_Object)#32 (5) {
            ["_apiKey":protected]=>
             string(32) "my_key_here"
              ["_values":protected]=>
               array(2) {
                ["amount"]=>
                  int(0)
                ["currency"]=>
                  string(3) "usd"

                etc...
```

I've tried doing the following but it only resulted in an error. I'm trying to get the amount of pending and available.

```
<?php
  var_dump($balance);
  /*Issue Line Below*/
  echo $balance->pending->amount;
?>
```

The error I get is: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: It looks like pending is an array of objects, have you tried `$balance->pending[0]->amount`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `pending` is not an object but an array which is why PHP is throwing that error. Your code should be something like this:

```
$response = Stripe_Balance::retrieve();
foreach($response->pending as $pendingBalance)
{
  echo "Pending balance of " . $pendingBalance->amount . " in " . $pendingBalance->currency . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way

```
$balance = Stripe_Balance::retrieve();
$balanceArr = $balance->__toArray(true);
$amount = $balanceArr['pending']['0']['amount'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is because you're using a function as a wrapper to this. There's really no need to define your own function whose sole purpose is to call another function, and doing so in this case may be causing the issue. The first step I'd take is to remove the function wrapper and just use the Stripe library directly.

Hope that helps,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here years after this question was asked, here's another example using [PHP reset function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
$balance = Stripe_Balance::retrieve();
$amount =  reset($balance->pending)->amount;
```